# Is there something for winning all rounds of the duels against Apollo, or just winning the duel in general?

Tags: cross-code

I saw [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/CrossCode/comments/bqu05u/emilie_races/eq95sw5/):

> Yeah that's what I wound up doing. Finished the game today actually. But it turns out that I lost a round to Apollo in the first fight only so... RIP.

...

And I managed to not let Apollo win any rounds of the ''first'' of his '5 out of 9 rounds' duels.

Now I'm on the second duel. Do I need to do perfectly this time to get something special? Or is it just winning against him in the duels at all, that I need to care about?

Something being a Trophy / Achievement / Dialogue, etc. Anything in-game that changes with a 5-1 Lea Victory vs. a 5-0 Lea Victory in the second duel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, getting 5-0 on every duel nets the True Spheromancer trophy, which is one of the Special trophies, not a Combat trophy.